# Extracting substrings between single quotes

Tags: python, regex, string

I am new in python and trying to extract substrings between single quotes. Do you know how to do this with regex?

E.G input

```
 text = "[(u'apple',), (u'banana',)]"
```

I want to extract apple and banana as list items like `['apple', 'banana']`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Pre-emptive note to potential answerers: if you give a solution using regex, make sure that it works on tricky strings like `"[(u'this string contains\' an escaped quote mark and\\ an escaped slash',)]"`

Comment: You can try a non greedy regex, `'.*?'` but this does not work with the conditions that Kevin has mentioned. However it works fine with the sample input you have provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = "[(u'apple',), (u'banana',)]"   

print(re.findall(r"\(u'(.*?)',\)", text)
['apple', 'banana']

text = "[(u'this string contains\' an escaped quote mark and\\ an escaped slash',)]"
print(re.findall(r"\(u'(.*?)',\)", text)[0])
this string contains' an escaped quote mark and \ an escaped slash
```

Answer (score 5):

In the general case, to extract any chars in between single quotes, the most efficient regex approach is

```
re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", text) # to also extract empty values
re.findall(r"'([^']+)'", text) # to only extract non-empty values
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9VLkuj/1/).

**Details**

- `'` - a single quote (no need to escape inside a double quote string literal)
- `([^']*)` - a [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that captures any 0+ (or 1+ if you use `+` quantifier) chars other than `'` (the `[^...]` is a **negated character class** that matches any chars other than those specified in the class)
- `'` - a closing single quote.

Note that [**`re.findall`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) only returns captured substrings if capturing groups are specified in the pattern:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/CAyGiA):

```
import re
text = "[(u'apple',), (u'banana',)]"
print(re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", text))
# => ['apple', 'banana']
```

**Escaped quote support**

If you need to support escaped quotes (so as to match `abc\'def` in `'abc\'def'` you will need a regex like

```
re.findall(r"'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'", text, re.DOTALL) # in case the text contains only "valid" pairs of quotes
re.findall(r"(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'", text, re.DOTALL) # if your text is too messed up and there can be "wild" single quotes out there
```

See [regex variation 1](https://regex101.com/r/9VLkuj/2) and [regex variation 2](https://regex101.com/r/9VLkuj/3) demos.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\\)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a backslash immediately to the left of the current position
- `(?:\\\\)*` - 0 or more consecutive double backslashes (since these are not escaping the neighboring character)
- `'` - an open `'`
- `([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)` - Group 1 (what will be returned by `re.findall`)matching...

  - `[^'\\]*` - 0 or more chars other than `'` and `\`
  - `(?:` - start of a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that matches

    - `\\.` - any escaped char (a backslash and any char including line breaks due to the `re.DOTALL` modifier)
    - `[^'\\]*` - 0 or more chars other than `'` and `\`
- `)*` - ... zero or more times
- `'` - a closing `'`.

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/GOAi0Z):

```
import re
text = r"[(u'apple',), (u'banana',)] [(u'apple',), (u'banana',), (u'abc\'def',)] \\'abc''def' \\\'abc   'abc\\\\\'def'"
print(re.findall(r"(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'", text))
# => apple, banana, apple, banana, abc\'def, abc, def, abc\\\\\'def
```

Answer (score 2):

You may alternatively use `ast.literal_eval` then extract the first item by list comprehension:

```
from ast import literal_eval

text = "[(u'apple',), (u'banana',)]"

literal_eval(text)
Out[3]: [(u'apple',), (u'banana',)]

[t[0] for t in literal_eval(text)]
Out[4]: [u'apple', u'banana']
```